# Delivery Status Notification (DSN) in evolution?

Tags: email, evolution

Is there a way to get a DSN (Delivery Status Notification) - not MDN - in evolution?

- am I blind and didn't find the setting?
- is there a "hidden" setting via dconf/gsettings?
- or has an (additional) plugin to be installed?

...and is the solution applied once for the current message or as default for all messages or is maybe both possible?

Comment: Unless you're talking about *Options › Return Receipt* (which is the MDN, I'm afraid) you're not the only one missing that. I'm using Evo for more than 10 years now and still didn't find it. I would be surprised if it were there and I was too blind to see it that long.

Comment: @Izzy: yes, you are right *Return Receipt* is *MDN*...! **:-(**

Comment: @Izzy: by the way... i assume you talked about "Request ***Read** Receipt*", since in Evolution 3.18 there was nothing else under "*Options*"!?

Comment: Ahm… yes, that's the term I was after. I miss the other ones, too. Wondering why that's not implemented in a "popular" client like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no such option as of today, at least not in the current HEAD of `evolution-data-server` which is responsible for SMTP communication. 
DSN works by adding a parameter named `NOTIFY` to the `RCPT TO` line in SMTP communication. [Looking at the function `smtp_rcpt` on line 1562 in `camel_smtp_transport.c`](https://github.com/GNOME/evolution-data-server/blob/4963283ad8c144a6daab0d24ba1c404bb1c8d61f/src/camel/providers/smtp/camel-smtp-transport.c#L1562) the `RCPT TO` command is created like this

```
cmdbuf = g_strdup_printf ("RCPT TO:<%s>\r\n", recipient);
```

There is no hint of `NOTIFY` at all.